# 2010 Dodge Caravan

Tags: dodge, heater, heater-blower, caravan

When 2001 Dodge Dakota heater wouldn't work at all speeds I changed the blower motor resistor and all was well. Tried the same thing when 2010 Dodge Caravan heater was doing the same thing and it didn't help, still only worked on 2 lower speeds. Can it just be the blower motor itself or is the resistor the only one that controls settings?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Check the blower motor fuse(s).

Comment: I assume it is Not an ATC system? (Automatic temperature control)